Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop Experiencing constant mouse and keyboard freezes
On a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop on an old Dell Precision T3600, I'm experiencing constant mouse and keyboard freezes that require a reboot to recover.  I've also tried to install 24.04 on a virtual machine on an XCP-ng 8.2.1 host but cannot even complete the install process without having to reboot the VM and rebuild it.
I've never had this kind of problems with an Ubuntu long term release going back to the original one in June 2006 or any previous release going back to the original one in 2004.
Has anyone else had the mouse / keyboard freeze problem and, if so, were you able to resolve the issue and how?  As it is ... this new long term release is completely unusable.

"Freezes" may have a variety of possible software and/or hardware causes. Somebody else's freezes may be unrelated to yours, so their solution might not help you. Please add diagnostic information to the question.

If it were me I would try another unix distro to either eliminate or confirm the problem is Ubuntu.

24.04 is still a brand new version of ubuntu. I would recommend to use the previous LTS version instead. It's far more stable.
The best would be to wait for a few weeks or a month. Maybe until the first .-Version is released (24.04.1 or so).
Many people are facing problems with the upgrade process or ubuntu 24.04 in general.

Lunar Cultist ... Having used Ubuntu since it was first released in 2004, I'm very well aware of everything you said.  But I'm trying to evaluate the newest release and simply see what is new in it.  If I can't install it or if once it is installed, it continually freezes then I cannot even investigate the newest features.  I have 22.04 running on multiple servers and workstations.  I'm interested in finding out about 24.04.

I've narrowed the freeze issue down to Nautilus.  I can load Nautilus and the mouse and keyboard still respond until I click the mouse cursor in the Nautilus window.  If I click inside the Nautilus window, the cursor freezes and the keyboard becomes unresponsive.  The only way to recover is a hard reboot.

After rebooting, at the login, I changed to Xorg from Wayland (Ubuntu), loaded Nautilus and clicked inside the Nautilus window, but no freeze occurred.  Now I can at least map a drive to my NAS.

My mouse is freezing from time to time as well and I have randomly discovered that the pointer gets unstuck when I run the command xkill in the terminal. I don't really get the reason behind it but it's better than restarting the PC.
